# python if condition "and" keyword issue

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I simply trying calling this code

```
uname=""
passwd="jhj"
if uname =="":print "uname"
if passwd=="":print "passwd"
if not uname and passwd:
    print "either"
```

and the output is:

```
uname
either
```

shouldn't It be "uname"?how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix would be

```
if not uname and not passwd:
```

since it evaluates as

```
if (not uname) and (not passwd):
```

or

```
if not (uname or passwd):
```

but this would not work as awaited if neither `uname` nor `password` are provided (it would print all three).

You could change the logic to this construct where only one `print` is executed:

```
uname = ""
passwd = "jhj"

if not (uname or passwd):
    print "either"
elif not uname:
    print "uname"
elif not passwd:
    print "passwd"
```

Comment: or indeed `not(uname and password)`.

Comment: @katrielalex Not the same thing. If one evaluates to ``True``, ``not(uname and password)`` will return True. What you want for equivalence is ``not (uname or password)``.

Comment: De Morgan's Law: not a and not b == not (a or b)

Comment: @Lattyware - of course, this is more elegant, but the more verbatim approach should help the OP understand the logic easier.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here is this:

```
if (not uname) and passwd:
```

If you want to check if they are both false, you need to do:

```
if not uname and not passwd:
```

Note that:

```
if not (uname and passwd):
```

Is not the same thing, as if one item is True, the whole thing will evaluate false. If you want to do it with one `not`, the correct logic is:

```
if not (uname or passwd):
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to apply the `not` in `if not uname and passwd` to both uname and passwd:

`if not uname and not passwd`

or:

`if not any((uname, passwd))`